# how to fix deprecated: startManagingCursor()

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

i have a code with desperated

```
startManagingCursor(timelineCursor)
```

that code is not work again, but how must i change my code use loadmanager, i have read some blog but i'm still confused. can you give me any example?

this is my full code

```
setContentView(R.layout.timeline);
        try {  

        homeTimeline = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.homeList);
        //instantiate database helper 
        timelineHelper = new NiceDataHelper(this);   
        //get the database 
        timelineDB = timelineHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         //query the database, most recent tweets first 
        timelineCursor = timelineDB.query("home", null, null, null, null, null, "update_time DESC");
        startManagingCursor(timelineCursor);
        //instantiate adapter 
        timelineAdapter = new UpdateAdapter(this, timelineCursor);
        //this will make the app populate the new update data in the timeline view 
        homeTimeline.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
        //instantiate receiver class for finding out when new updates are available 
        niceStatusReceiver = new TwitterUpdateReceiver(); 
        //register for updates 
        registerReceiver(niceStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter("TWITTER_UPDATES"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "teest", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //start the Service for updates now 
        this.getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TimeLineService.class));

        } 
    catch(Exception te) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to fetch timeline: " + te.getMessage()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

the loader frame work isn't too difficult to understand once it's broken down. You will need to use the manager as well as a set of your own custom callbacks. This article should help http://hiqes.com/android-loaders/